# Map composite key sort

Tags: couchdb

I try to display app's log entries from couchdb - each log entry contains timestamp, log tag and client's remote IP, my map function is :

```
{
"_id": "_design/log",
"language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "browse": {
           "map": "function(doc){ if (doc.type=='log') {emit([doc.date,doc.tag,doc.ip], doc);}}"
       }
   }
}
```

**Now how can I get log entries for specified IP(tag) sorted by date ?**

Already tried variants of : /_design/log/_view/browse?startkey=["info","8.8.8.8"] with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Your start key needs 3 elements: date, tag, and ip.

Your unsuccessful query only has 2 elements in the start key.

There is some documentation out there for composite keys.  In the example used, they have a different key for year, month, and day.  You can find the example in this book:  http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018247.do

Comment: I don't enter 'date' key because I want all 'info' entries for ip 8.8.8.8

Comment: What if you re-order the keys in the map-reduce function so that the date key is last instead of first?

Comment: Results from reduce are not sorted so I don't get results in date order.emitting [tag,ip] maybe offer some variants of sorting in reduce.

Comment: Can you pass a regular expression for the first element of the start key?

Comment: Good question !, I found that only {} works as 'last element'

Comment: wait, if date is the last element of the key, shouldn't the results be sorted by date and filtered to a given ip address and a given tag?

Comment: results are sorted by key [tag, ip, date] which get results not sorted in date order, if I put [date, tag, ip] key - results are sorted in date order but I can't obtain results for tag,ip pair

Answer (score -1):

Map function:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'log') {
    emit([doc.tag, doc.ip, doc.date], 1);
  }
}
```

Query parameters *(properly url-encoded)*:

```
?startkey=["info","8.8.8.8"]&endkey=["info","8.8.8.8",{}]&include_docs=true
```

The results are sorted by date because tag and ip are fixed.

Comment: This is ok, but how can I get all 'info' entries sorted by date ? - another view?

Comment: Maybe. A view in CouchDB is like an index in a relational DB: if you need to query/sort by a given field, you need a view, or you can filter/sort the results on the client, or you can use a [list function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html). There's no single good response, you need to evaluate pros and cons of each solution for your use-case.